# Add Python3 build system to Sublime text but not worked

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am following the book "Python Crash Course". I add python3 build system by the code:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

I run a code like hello world and it show an error

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['python3', '-i', '-u', 'E:\\hello.py']]
[dir: E:\]
[path: E:\VKU\Java\Mooc.fi\Eclipse\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Java\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\Process Lasso\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\Trn_Huy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\Trn_Huy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\Trn_Huy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\Trn_Huy\.dotnet\tools]
[Finished]
```

I was google but still don't find any solution.
I try the Python in default sublimetext and it still run normally.
I know I can use another IDLE to learn but I still want to know why it didn't worked.

Comment: The command in Windows is `python`, not `python3`.

Comment: Sublime Text usually works on Windows without any additional configuration. What happens if you run your file with the default Python build system, and not this custom build system?

Comment: Indeed if you are using ST4 the build that ships with Sublime for Python should work out of the box for anyone on any platform that has Python installed and properly configured, so long as they are using Python 3 and not Python 2.